# Octave help command

Tags: command-line-interface, octave

Whenever I use help command in Octave I get the following error like;

```
octave 1:> help plot
error: system: unable to start subprocess for '"makeinfo --no-headers --no-warn --force --no-validate --output=- C:\Users\shashank\AppData\Local\Temp\octave-help-rqFGAY"'
error: called from __makeinfo__ at line 140 column 20 help at line 102 column 22
```

how to correct it.

```
octave:2> help help 
error: system: unable to start subprocess for '"makeinfo --no-headers --no-warn --force --no-validate --output=- C:\Users\shashank\AppData\Local\Temp\octave-help-U1Yzip"'
error: called from __makeinfo__ at line 140 column 20 help at line 102 column 22
```

How to correct it?

Comment: How long have you been using this installation of Octave? If it's new, I'd recommend a reinstall.

Comment: i tried installing different versions and reinstall but nothing works

Comment: was there ever a solution for this?